# How to add a public ssh key using debian preseed file?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, preseed

Using debian preseeding, I want to copy a public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` with correct permissions so that I can use ansible to configure the rest of system.

I already selected openssh-server to be installed by selecting `d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential` in the preseed file.

Would this late command work?

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target mkdir -p /root/.ssh; \
in-target /bin/sh -c "echo 'ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1IAg1wilR9asDXIPwTsvZXasdTXqasdKv0rIqqweAtxGVgup foobar' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"; \
in-target chown -R root:root /root/.ssh/; \
in-target chmod 644 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys; \
in-target chmod 700 /root/.ssh/
```

Comment: the `preseed.cfg`-template contains a network-section where you can edit the line `#d-i network-console/authorized_keys_url string http://10.0.0.1/openssh-key`. maybe is this a feature you are looking for.

Comment: @anion That is *not* the authorized key file for the root user in the target system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way.
There's nothing more to say, but I need 30 characters.